# How to convert a fractional into an integral equation?

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

```
(y1 - 1)/(x1 - 2) + (y2 - 1)/(x2 - 2) == 0
```

How to convert a fractional equation into an integral equation?

to get the result:

```
(y1 - 1) (x2 - 2) + (y2 - 1) (x1 - 2) == 0
```

or

```
(y1 - 1)/(x1 - 2) + (y2 - 1)/(x2 - 2) == m
```

to get the result:

```
(y1 - 1) (x2 - 2) + (y2 - 1) (x1 - 2) == m(x1 - 2)(x2 - 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[fix];
fix[eqIn_Equal] := Module[{eq = eqIn},
  eq = eq /. (any1_/any2_) :> HoldForm[any1]/HoldForm[any2];
  eq = Together[eq];
  eq = If[Last[eq] === 0,
    Numerator[First[eq]] == 0
    ,
    Numerator[First[eq]] == Denominator[First[eq]]*Last[eq]
    ];
  ReleaseHold[eq]
  ]
```

To use:

```
fix[(y1 - 1)/(x1 - 2) + (y2 - 1)/(x2 - 2) == 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
fix[(y1 - 1)/(x1 - 2) + (y2 - 1)/(x2 - 2) == m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
fix[a/b + c/d == m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
fix[a/b + c/d + e/f == 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

There is the cross multiplication fomula for rationals Get numerators and denominators

```
(3 (y1 - 1)/(u (x1 - 2)) - 4 (y2 - 1)/(v (x2 - 2)) ==  m) /.
 {a__Times + b__Times == m_ :> 
   0 == Plus @@ ( Cancel[Denominator[a] Denominator[b] #] &) /@
{ a, b, -m}}


0==-m u v (-2+x1) (-2+x2)+3 v (-2+x2) (-1+y1)-4 u (-2+x1) (-1+y2)
```

The result is  logical non-equivalent, because it is True for x1,x2=2. Therefore, Simplify with Assumptions and penalties for inverse Powers in the ComplexityFunction.

```
  Assuming[ x1!=2&&x2!=2&& u!=0&&v!=0,
    FullSimplify[ 3(y1-1)/(u(x1-2))-4(y2-1)/(v (x2-2))==m,
    ComplexityFunction->
 (LeafCount[#]+
   1000 Count[#,_^_?Negative,12]
   -1000 Count[#,_Plus*_Plus,12]&)]] 

3 v (-2+x2) (-1+y1)==u (-2+x1) (m v (-2+x2)+4 (-1+y2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
removedeno[eq_Equal] := removedeno[eq, Subtract @@ eq // Together // Denominator]
removedeno[a_ == b_, deno_] := removedeno[a, deno] == removedeno[b, deno]
removedeno[a_ + b_, deno_] := removedeno[a, deno] + removedeno[b, deno]
removedeno[a_, deno_] := a deno 

eq1 = (y1 - 1)/(x1 - 2) + (y2 - 1)/(x2 - 2) == 0;    
eq2 = (y1 - 1)/(x1 - 2) + (y2 - 1)/(x2 - 2) == m;

removedeno /@ {eq1, eq2}
(* {(-2 + x2) (-1 + y1) + (-2 + x1) (-1 + y2) == 0, 
    (-2 + x2) (-1 + y1) + (-2 + x1) (-1 + y2) == m (-2 + x1) (-2 + x2)} *)
```