# How to automatically solve the coordinates of a fixed point passing through a parametric linear equation?

Tags: equation-solving

After previous calculations, this equation was obtained like this:

```
y == 1 - 2 k + k x
```

How to find the coordinates of the fixed point it passes through?

The principle of manual calculation is as follows:

1. Extract the common factor for parameter k to obtain the equation:

```
y==1+k(x-2)
```

2. The formula in parentheses containing parameters is equal to 0, and the corresponding fixed point coordinate value is obtained by solving it

```
x-2==0     so  x==2
```

3.Since the parameter containing part is 0, we can naturally obtain the remaining coordinate values of the fixed point

```
y==1
```

So this straight line equation passes through a fixed point `{2, 1}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once again, you should put more effort in understanding the answers you've obtained:

```
Solve[ForAll[{k}, y == 1 - 2 k + k x], {x, y}]
(* {{x -> 2, y -> 1}} *)

SolveAlways[y == 1 - 2 k + k x, k]
(* {{x -> 2, y -> 1}} *)
```

The method is the same as that used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/284020/1871), and [Domen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/75628/domen) already mentioned the relevant post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283938/how-to-transform-elliptic-equation-and-hyperbola-equation-into-standard-form#comment707265_283938).

Comment: ```Solve[ForAll[{k}, y == k/(k^2 - 1) x + k/(k^2 - 1) - 1], {x, y}]```Why does this equation have no solution at a fixed point?

Comment: @csn899 Because `k^2 != 1`. Similar issue has been mentioned in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/284078/1871) you received, so, for the third time: please put more effort in understanding the answers you've obtained.

Comment: ```Solve[ForAll[{k}, k^2 != 1, 
  y == k/(k^2 - 1) x + 2 k/(k^2 - 1) - 1], {x, y}]```It's ok!

Comment: ```SolveAlways[y == k/(k^2 - 1) x + 2 k/(k^2 - 1) - 1, k]```the same